# Why can't program write to HKEY_CURRENTUSER in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, registry

The code below fails when running on Windows 7, with default access levels.  (This is a C# application, built with Visual Studio 2010).  I am writing to HKEY_CurrentUser, which is where I should be allowed to create and read keys.

Do I need to modify my program's manifest? or is there another arcane trick?

Under Windows 7, If you dial down the notify setting on your user account, the code works. But not with the factory setting.  Should programmers give up on the registry?

```
RegistryKey regsoftware = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
RegistryKey regsw = regsoftware.CreateSubKey("MyCompanyName");

regsw.SetValue("User", Id);
regsw.SetValue("Pwd", encodeString(Pw));
```

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: The registry has always been a festering pile of rotten diaper fillings.

Comment: Are you accidentally running your program and regedit under different user accounts (e.g. your account isn't an administrator, and you elevate one of the two programs, thus running it as a different user)?

Comment: I'm not tried to run my program under any particular account.  We provide our program to clients who run it on their own computers.  As a convenience we save some settings to the part of the registry *designed* for that purpose.  Recent microsoft "innovations" cause this to fail - particularily under windows 7.  How can I compile my program to defend against this type of innovation?

Comment: can you define fail? Are you getting access denied, or does the key not get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if you wanna run your app with admin privileges you can try this.

Go to Project->properties->Drop down "Linker" option->Manifest File->in your right pane check "UAC Execution Level" -> choose "requireAdministrator"
(I'm using VS2008 hope it should be same in VS2010).
Thatz all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your program as an administrator. you can check whether an operation needs elevation or not and elevate an operation if needed with the **WinAPI CodePack** for .NET Framework.

Comment: How do I elevate this operation?  Also, why are programs not allowed to write to this key?  The design of the registry was to encourage programs to write data here to prevent proliferation of INI files.  Why make it hard to write the data?

Comment: your problem is not specific to this key, if your program needs to write data to the registry, it will need administrative privileges, so either the end-user has to start the program as an administrator or you can elevate the operation with code. look for **WinAPI CodePack** and on MSDN for more info.